# Login MSSQL using Active Directory account from local Windows account

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, windows-authentication

Due to Coronavirus, we on my company are working from home. I had setup a virtual machine and am using VPN to connect to company's intranet.

It happens that we use company's AD account to log in MSSQL. We log in Windows with our account, and use Windows Authentication to log in MSSQL.

Now, I'm unable to log in local Windows using AD. I'd need to configure it to connect to AD, but for that Windows/PC needs a machine digital certificate, and be approved by some domain admin. That won't happen.

Anyway, I'm looking for a way to run SSMS using AD account, without needing to use it on Windows. I tried `Run as different user` but it also didn't work.

Comment: You could RDP to the server and run SSMS there.  If SSMS isn't installed on the server you'd have to install it first...

Comment: Also, see the answer by "Dave" with 10 votes at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849149/connect-different-windows-user-in-sql-server-management-studio-2005-or-later/49460747.  Seems like I tried this just for fun once and it worked.

Comment: tnx! I'm gonna read it. Unfortunately admin staff doesn't allow us to remotely login on server's Windows. I've been asking that for years and they won't allow it.

Comment: The cmdkey, runas /netonly and credential manager answers at the other question are the correct ones (they all do basically the same thing).  You don't need to domain-join your computer or RDP into the SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft.  I wasn't sure if the runas would work if the workstation can't use the domain.

Comment: Yeah, all answers there point to runas. Unfortunately I tried it and it didn't work. I guess to use AD accounts to login MSSQL we need local Windows to be added to that AD. I'm unable to do that so it won't work :/